# Making the prediction model with several explanatory variables

Tags: statistics, regression

Now I'm trying to make some predictors with several explantory variables.

I want to ask you whether my method is wrong.

I have one score (which will be Y here) and 4 features (X1, X2, X3, and X4) with 100 observations.

Now I investigated the relationships between Y and X1, X2, X3, and X4 individually by using Pearson's correlation coefficients and linear regression (beta).

Using the relation, I made some predictor of Y through the weighted sum.

I made step-wise linear regression model and used the weight (it showed increased correlation coefficients and beta).

Due to the lack of my knowledge, I want to know whether or not it is valid approach and get some tips (other approaches when X's have different unit).

Thank you.

KHW.

---

Thank you for your advise.

Actually, I know that the measrues X probabily have linear relationships between Y. My approach was to investigate Pearson's corrleation coefficient and regression beta for X1, X2, X3, and X4 individualy. I found linear relationships between the features and Y, but I wanted to increase predictability (r and beta here) by combining the features. Hence I made Y' = B(0) + B(1) * X1 + B(2) * X2 + ... + B(4) * X4, where Y' is the estimated Y and B(0) is an intercept.

First, I made Y' = B(0) + B(1)* X1 + B(4) * X4 using step-wise linear regression.

Second, I made Y' = B(0) + B(1) * X1 + B(2) * X2 + ... + B(4) * X4 using multiple linear regression.

They fitted quite good, but I worry that I actually want to say the features could predict Y, but choosing coefficient using regression requires Y, which means it is not a predictor.

Could k-fold cross validation be an way to validate?

Thank you

Comment: I suggest visual inspection of scatterplots for Y vs. X1, Y vs. X2, etc. to ensure that the relationships are linear, or if some other obvious type of relationship can be seen on the plots. This can help to make certain you have not missed some obvious non-linear relationship such as an exponential.

Comment: Thank you for advice! now I want to ask a few more question, but the comment area does not allow me to write longer, so I editted the post. It will be grateful that you give me some more comments.

Comment: You are correct, X1,X2,X3,X4 are used to predict Y in the mathematical model created by the regression. One measure of the model is to ask, "How much of the variance in Y is accounted for by the model?" and I do this by calculating R-squared (R2) as "R2 = 1.0 - (absolute_error_variance / Y_variance)". If the R2 value is 0,50, your model explains 50 percent of the variance in Y. If the R2 value is 0.99, then your model explains 99 percent of the variance in Y. There are many statistical measures used for goodness-of-fit, and the R-squared is very widely used in regression analysis.

Comment: I appreciate your comments. I will compute R-squared first and search the others. Thank you.